# What is a "un-pooled" buffer in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, buffer

I came across this term when reading the Buffers' documentation Node.js, I noticed that they wrote "un-pooled" and not "unpooled" as in Netty, for example, if the concept is the same, please try to explain it in a different way than it has already been done on similar questions. My second question, if there are "un-pooled" Buffers, are there "pooled" Buffers, and what are they?

Answer (score 1):

**Non-pooled Buffers:**

In non-pooled buffers, each buffer is allocated independently, and the memory is managed manually by the developer

When you create a non-pooled buffer, it directly allocates the required amount of memory from the system.

```
// Example of creating a non-pooled buffer
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(10);
```

**Pooled Buffers:**

Pooled buffers are managed by a pool or a pool-like mechanism, where a pool of pre-allocated buffers is maintained.

Instead of directly allocating memory from the system each time, a pooled buffer is obtained from the pool. After use, it can be returned to the pool for later reuse.

```
// Example of creating a pooled buffer
const pool = new BufferPool(10); 
const buffer = pool.allocate(10);
// After use, return the buffer to the pool
pool.release(buffer);
```